# It it possible to order an array of objects by an array element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have an array like this:

```
[
  {names: [
     {firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Jones"},
     {firstName: "Martha", lastName: "Jones"}
   ]
  },
  {names: [
     {firstName: "Jim", lastName: "Franklin"},
     {firstName: "Jill", lastName: "Franklin"}
   ]
  }
]
```

What expression would I use in ng-repeat to order by the first lastName of each record (e.g. names[0].lastName)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
ng-repeat="e in entries | orderBy:'names[0].lastName'"
```

or:

```
ng-repeat="e in entries | orderBy:'-names[0].lastName'"
```

for reverse order.

Comment: It looks like my real problem was that orderBy doesn't work with associative arrays, I was just incorrectly attributing the problem to the nested array.